# SQL Server PIVOT - Vertical to Horizontal - error

Tags: pivot

Will you please help to check this?

```
CREATE TABLE Sales 
(
    Category NVARCHAR(30),
    Region NVARCHAR(30),
    Amount MONEY
)

DELETE FROM Sales

INSERT INTO Sales
VALUES 
('X','1',24),
('X','2',NULL),
('X','3',165),
('X','4',36),
('Y','1',38),
('Y','2',181),
('Y','3',287),
('Y','4',NULL),
('Z','1',83),
('Z','2',55),
('Z','3',33),
('Z','4',44)

DECLARE @SQLStr NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQLStr = COALESCE(@SQLStr + ',' ,'')+ [a].[Column]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Region AS [Column]
      FROM Sales) AS a

SET @SQLStr = 'SELECT Category, ' + @SQLStr + ' FROM (SELECT Category, Region, Amount FROM Sales) sq '
              + ' PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR Region IN (' + @SQLStr + ')) AS pt'
PRINT @SQLStr
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStr
```

I get an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Initially, the column 'Region' is `INT` type (values are 1, 2, 3, 4)
The same error, then I change its type to `NVARCHAR(30)`, but the same error happens. Please help.

In reality, I want to transpose the vertical product usage data to horizontal.

Please see the image link

[Please see this screen shot, this is what I really want to achieve](http://snag.gy/V7gsZ.jpg)

As you see, the date is transposed to horizontal. I want to populate the usage data to horizontal way for my analysis. Please help

The column header can be date? or have to be string?

Comment: Sorry mate, I also tried this SELECT Category, 1, 2, 3, 4 
FROM (SELECT Category, Region, Amount FROM Sales) sq  
     PIVOT (SUM(Amount) 
         FOR Region IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) AS pt. The same error message "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near '1'."

Comment: If the region values are string, the query is ok. No issue. But if it is number, it has errors. I do not understand why. As you see in the linked image, What I want to put the dates horizontally. Is it possible? I have not find example yet. please help.

Answer (score 0):

please add brackets with column name like below

```
DECLARE @SQLStr NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQLStr = COALESCE(@SQLStr + ',' ,'')+ +'['+[a].[Column]+']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Region AS [Column]
FROM @Sales) AS a
```

You should always place square brackets around the column names []:

From MSDN:

The first character must be one of the following:

```
A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).
```

If it is anything else, then you will need to use the square brackets. []

Comment: Can I transpose vertal dates to horizonal dates? .e.g. 1/1/2015 1/2/2015 1/3/2015 ......1/8/2015? the columns header have to be string or can be the date format? thanks

Comment: That is great Virendra, you rock. Your answers help me out of the trouble. Thank you.

Comment: I have problem now, if I change the original table structure for the field  'Region' from NVARCHAR to INT. Then Reload the data to reflect this. Then run the query, I have the error below, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ']' to data type int.". In my case, the Region value is 1,2. 3 or 4. I want to test if in this case, the Region as columns in the transposed table, what can be? (If you check my linked image, you will see actually, I want to test, how could I make dates as columns in the horizonal table). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: + operator for INT values does not concatenate string it try for addition, thats  why your are getting error you can try this `SELECT @SQLStr = COALESCE(@SQLStr + ',' ,'')+'['+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[a].[Column])+']
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Region AS [Column]
      FROM @Sales) AS a`

Comment: you have to explicitly convert INT values to NVARCHAR when concatenating them

Comment: Thanks Virendra. You help.

Comment: Hi V, where can I upvote your answer? I do not know how.pls advise

Comment: I click it but I get this "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: Hi V, Thanks again for your help. Now back to my real work, I find dates are not in sequence as column headers. E.g. 2014/05/29 then 2014/06/24 then 2014/05/28, etc. How can i sort it out? please advise

Comment: sorry i m unable to generate scenario, my solution is automatically sorted